# What did President Putin mean by "Кто в лавке-то останется? Кто работать будет?"

Tags: цитата

In one of his interviews, President Putin used the expression "Кто в лавке-то останется? Кто работать будет?", apparently alluding to some well-known joke, but I can't find any reference to the original.

Is this expression idiomatic? What does it mean? What is its origin?

Comment: Asking for a joke reference is off-topic unless it has something to do with Russian language as a topic

Comment: if you fail to find something at google you can try your luck at yandex  - https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=99&text=%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B2+%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82

Comment: @il--ya sure, let's think what would be a better category. However it's not about being trivial - it's about being off-topic.

Comment: @shabunc: I've changed the wording in the question, does it look good now?

Comment: @Quassnoi thanks! I agree with you that in this form it's on-topic

Answer (score 13):

This sentence alludes to a century-old Jewish joke
(where "Jewish" doesn't imply that it's "told by Jews," but rather "about Jews").

And old Jew is on his deathbed, surrounded by his weeping family.
In a weak voice, he asks:
— Is Sara here?
— Yes, honey, I'm right beside you.
— Is Joseph here?
— Yes, Dad, here I am.
— Is Samuel here?
— Yes, Grandpa, I'm with you.
— А кто же в лавке остался ?! [So who's minding the shop?!]

Comment: Significant part of the fun of this joke is the way of delivering it. While most lines of the dying man are spoken in a weak, frail voice, the last line is spoken in a strong, healthy voice, making an impression that now he is not really going to die.

Comment: The joke belongs to the Jewish culture and to a quite big group of jokes referenced as Jewish humor. First of all the jokes are "created by Jews" inside the Jewish community/neighborhood.